# Equivalent of X11 forwarding for locally displaying GUI running on a remote Windows server

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-control

I have a computer with Windows 10, and I would like to run a visual application on it, but without displaying it in the remote server (i.e. with nothing like TeamViewer).

In Linux, this is possible with SSH X11 forwarding, but my question is: is there a way to display the GUI of a single remotely running Windows 10 application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft supports this with a technology they call RemoteApp, but only on their Server (not Desktop) Products.  This is an overview [HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055(v=ws.11).aspx)